# is an inner member of an outer-join clause. This is not allowed if the table also participates in a regular join clause

Tags: plsql, isql

I have a below working query:

```
`select distinct t1.ExNo,
 t3.ExDesc from table1 t1
 left join table2 t2 on t1.ExNo = t2.ExNo
join table3 t3 on t3.ExTyp = case 
    when t1.ExTyp = 'CONT'
        and t2.ExTyp is not null
        then t2.ExTyp
    else t1.ExTyp
    end
order by t1.ExNo;`
```

But if the same query modified as below and use, I am getting this error. Could you please rectify:

```
`select distinct t1.ExNo,
t3.ExDesc
from table1 t1 t1, table2 t2,table3 t3 where 
t1.ExNo *= t2.ExNo and 
t3.ExTyp = case 
    when t1.ExTyp = 'CONTNR'
        and t2.ExTyp is not null
        then t2.ExTyp
    else t1.ExTyp
    end
 order by t1.ExNo;`
```

**Error:**
**The table is an inner member of an outer-join clause. This is not allowed if the table also participates in a regular join clause.**

Comment: If a table is an inner member of an outer join, it cannot participate in both an outer join clause and a regular join clause.

Comment: Can you provide same sql logic with **Non-ANSI**  format?